# How to import QR reader Typescript package in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, qr-code

Using a QR code reader in my React / Typescript app. Importing both file in `package.json`:

```json
"qrcode.react": "^1.0.1",
"@types/qrcode.react": "^1.0.1",
```

also importing it:

> import QRCode from 'qrcode.react'

And using it in return.

```js
<QRCode className={styles.qrcode}
```

It works, but VS Code raise a warning:

```
'QRCode' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its instance type 'Component<CanvasQRCodeProps | SvgQRCodeProps, any, any>' is not a valid JSX element.
    The types returned by 'render()' are incompatible between these types.
      Type 'React.ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'import("/Users/kukodajanos/Workspace/Tikex/Portal/Team/node_modules/@types/react-date-range/node_modules/@types/react/index").ReactNode'.
        Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.ts(2786)
```

How to fix warning?

Comment: The readme for [qrcode.react](https://github.com/zpao/qrcode.react) says to import it as `import { QRCodeSVG } from 'qrcode.react';` or `import { QRCodeCanvas } from 'qrcode.react';`. Do those work?

Comment: What do you mean "Typescript package"? It's a package _with types_, and the fact that they're not even bundled suggests it's written in JS.

Comment: Oh apparently it _does_ have bundled types, per the icon on the NPM page, so why _are_ you installing the types separately? And why using v1?

Comment: Looks like they may have installed an old version of qrcode.react. The latest is 3.0.1., but they're on 1.0.x

Answer (score 0):

```
yarn upgrade qrcode.react@3.0.1
```